# Monaco editor set font size

Tags: css, monaco-editor

I am trying set the font size of the monaco editor by styling his surrounding div. That way is not working. So I have seen the monaco editor has an property font-size. So i tried it with this property. Unfortunately this also didn't work for me. The best way would be the way with CSS, because I am styling a few things simultaneously.

Answer (score 12):

There is an API for setting font-size, font-family, etc, Try not to Hack in the DOM since that probably won't be compatible in the future.

In your case, try this:

```js
var editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), {
    value: "// First line\nfunction hello() {\n\talert('Hello world!');\n}\n// Last line",
    language: "javascript",
    fontSize: "12px",
    lineNumbers: "off",
    roundedSelection: false,
    scrollBeyondLastLine: false,
    readOnly: false,
    theme: "vs-dark",
});
```

Checkout the [Monaco Editor Playground for Basic Editor Options](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#creating-the-editor-editor-basic-options)  and start typing properties. It will autocomplete and you will see all available configuration properties with descriptions - or alternatively go to the api docs reference. good luck

Comment: The field `fontSize` is a number, not a string. The value is parsed to a number and any non-number addition is ignored. The value is then set as `px`. Hence setting e.g. `16pt` will end up as `16px`, which is not the same. You can check that in the playground.

Comment: See also https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/2242

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if it's possible to style the editor with CSS. However, you can use the `fontSize` property to change the editor's font size.

```js
monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), {
    value: "function hello() {\n\talert('Hello world!');\n}",
    language: "javascript",
    fontSize: 20
});
```

Comment: That's great, Devid. Could you share the solution here for Juhuy?

Answer (score 2):

In react monaco use this options prop

```
      <Editor 
            height={config.height}
            defaultValue={config.value}
            theme={config.theme}
            language={config.language}
            onChange={handleEditorchange}
            options={{
                scrollBeyondLastLine:false,
                fontSize:"30px"
            }}
            />
```

Answer (score 1):

In Newer version, the fontSize must be a Number

```js
<Editor
  height="100vh"
  width="100%"
  theme="vs-dark"
  defaultLanguage="javascript"
  defaultValue={code}
  options={{
    fontSize: 20,
  }}
/>
```